# SQL Select decimal not 0

Tags: sql, decimal, where-clause

I am trying to create a select statemeny for SQL where I'm trying to view all results where the value is not zero in a field with the decimal type

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Decimalvalue !== '0';
```

is what I'm trying and it doesn't seem to work for me, Any ideas?

Comment: The type for Decimalvalue is Decimal with length 5,2 if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Decimalvalue <> '0';
```

Comment: Correction, accidentally took the last letter of the field name off when pasting in code, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The correct comparison operator in SQL is `<>`.  And, you shouldn't compare a known number to a string:

```
WHERE Decimalvalue <> 0;
```

Some considerations.  If you have `NULL` values, these will also be filtered out, so you might want:

```
WHERE Decimalvalue <> 0 or DecimalValue is null;
```

You are using the word "decimal", perhaps without realizing that it has a specific meaning in SQL.  "Decimal" refers to a fixed point representation, rather than a floating point representation.  With floating point values, you can have results that look exactly the same, but differ at the nth decimal place.  In that case, you can do something like:

```
WHERE abs(Decimalvalue) > 0.0001 or DecimalValue is null;
```

Or whatever threshold you are comfortable with.

Comment: Tried all of those am getting no results back (i know there is one with a value of 65.50 I used decimal for the fixed point representation as im using this field to represent money

Comment: I stand corrected that does work, accidentally took the last letter of the field name off when pasting in code, thanks